# Why can't I edit my own comments after some time has passed?

Tags: discussion, comments, reputation

If I add a new comment and I want to change something i can edit it, when i come back 1 hour later I only have the possibility to delete my comment, but I can't edit my own comment, the symbol is grayed out.

I am not sure if it has to do something with 50 reputation treshold.
Wouldn't it be better to enable user from begin on to edit their own comments?

Comment: This is a network-wide feature, and reflects the fact that comments are intended to be 'transitory' (so deleting and re-writing is a reasonable position): probably there is something on this on meta.stackexchange.com

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/459/should-we-be-allowed-to-edit-comments

Comment: Ah Ok, the time window is 5 minutes. Shall this question then be closed as duplicate?